# Not seeing the "like it" button while it appears on localhost

Tags: 7

In which used [Wishlist module](https://www.drupal.org/project/wishlist) to create the "like it" button. On my localhost it is working fine, but not so on the production/testing server, where the button doesn't appear. The permissions on the server match the ones on localhost.

Why don't I see it on the server?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can you post some screenshots from your localhost and online website and get address to your online website?

Comment: @pankajKumar I think you've two accounts. Please use current account (from which you've posted this question) to edit your answer. then only your changes will be applied immediately

Comment: See [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: Assuming you have cleared all caches on your production server. Next I'd ask, what does the javascript console log say?